# Searching git commits by Android versionName

Tags: android, git, version-control, git-commit

I'm not sure what question I need to ask to google for this one. Maybe you can point me in the right direction.

I have a detected a bug in my app that started happenning between a range of versionName attribute changes in my AndroidManifest.xml.

The last versionName that was working okay was 4.8.1.50, and the one I saw the bug appear for the first time was 4.8.1.60.

Many git commits were made in between, affecting different files, some affecting the AndroidManifest, others did not.

Do you guys know if there is any way I can search and filter for all of those commits?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [`git bisect`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect)?

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a binary search method to find an exact commit where the problem starts.

As @Richard pointed out in a comment, you can use `git bisect` command. And here is the way to use it:

1. Move to a commit which is definitely broken: `git checkout <commit hash>`
2. Start the search process: `git bisect start`
3. And say that this commit is "bad": `git bisect bad`
4. Mark a commit that doesn't contain the issue for sure: `git bisect good <commit hash>`
5. Then repeat to mark good commits using `git bisect good`, each time `HEAD`  will be moved to a commit in the middle between the last `bad` and `good` using binary search.
6. When you find the issue, use `git bisect reset` to return the repo to initial state.

As a result, you can find the commit that brought the bug in `log n` steps, where `n` is the initial number of commits between the one that worked well and one where the problem is already reproduceable.

Comment: Yes, this is brilliant, I was able to review lots of commits and pinpoint the culprit in record time. Thanks a lot!